# addEventListener is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the text in a td cell to "Clicked!" when it is clicked upon, but it throws up an error when loading the JS. I have read around and know that it can't use an array like this but I don't know how to fix it.

```
window.addEventListener("load", table)

function table(){
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    tables.addEventListener("click", clicked);
}
```

Comment: This have been asked here so many times... "document.getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList of DOM elements. Each element has an addEventListener function, but the array doesn't have one."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns not a `Node` object, but `NodeList` object. You can access `Node` objects by index.

**Sample**:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

if (tables.length) {
 tables[0].addEventListener("click", clicked);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: You cannot use `.forEach()` on a NodeList.